# How to Remove Two Way Data Binding in Angular -2/4

Tags: javascript, angular, filter

I am developing a Multi Select dropdown in Angular which also has search. That is when I am parsing the input given from the input field through my master data and displaying only the filtered contents in the DOM. This is my function:

```
modifyFilter(value: any) {
        console.log('value', value); //The value passed from DOM
        this.filterContent = this.catalogManufacturerNames; /******/
        for(let i=0; i<this.catalogManufacturerNames.length;i++) {
         /* Search catalogManufacturerNames for the value and splice all
         filterContent not having the matching value */    
        }
    }
```

The problem with the code is that everytime the `modifyFilter` method is called the `catalogManufacturerNames` is also changed along with the `filterContent`. So every time I call `modifyFilter`, the row marked by /******/ the `filterContent` gets assigned to the previous `filterContent` than the global and presumably unchanged `catalogManufacturerNames`. I think the problem is that `filterContent` and `catalogManufacturerNames` get two way binded, but I do not know how to modify it to my requirements. Or is there any other way to go about it. Suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In this case you have to use **Object.assign** OR **DeepCopy**. It will create a copy of your object/variable so when ever you perform any filter on primary object it will not reflect in copied object and vice versa.

You can use `{},[]` as per your requirement.

**{}:** for single object

**[]:** for collection of objects

```
let copiedItem = Object.assign({}, copiedItem , PrimaryItem );
```

Please refer for detail: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

**Option: 2 Deep Copy**

```
DeepCopy(obj: any): any {
  let clonedObject;

  if (obj === null || typeof obj !== 'object') {
    return obj;
  }
  if (obj instanceof Array) {
    clonedObject = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
      clonedObject[i] = this.deepCopy(obj[i]);
    }
    return clonedObject;
  }
  if (obj instanceof Date) {
    clonedObject = new Date(obj.valueOf());
    return clonedObject;
  }
  if (obj instanceof RegExp) {
    clonedObject = RegExp(obj.source, obj.flags);
    return clonedObject;
  }
  if (obj instanceof Object) {
    clonedObject = new obj.constructor();
    for (const attr in obj) {
      if (obj.hasOwnProperty(attr)) {
        clonedObject[attr] = this.deepCopy(obj[attr]);
      }
    }
    return clonedObject;
  }
}
```

Call from component

```
let copiedItem: any[] = this.DeepCopy(PrimaryItem );
```

Comment: Wow! It worked. It catered to my needs and is working fine. Is there no other method with less technicality, like `=` is so simple compared to this right?

Comment: I meant that assigning by `=` is far simpler than the `Object.assign` right? I was wondering if there was any kind of a shorcut so that the syntax would be simpler.

Comment: yes, you are right assign by = is simpler then object.assign, but direct assignment not copy only object but also copy reference

Comment: I understand that from the Mozilla documentation, thanks to you. But is there no simpler alternative?

Comment: If so you can try, "let copiedItem = primaryItem.slice(0);"
Not sure about the code quality/best practice though.

Answer (score 2):

As a simpler alternative to using `Object.assign`, you can use the spread operator to copy the properties of the double-bound object to another:

```
this.filterContent = {...this.catalogManufacturerNames};
```

Reference:
http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/UsingObjectSpreadOperator.html

Comment: The method you suggest throws an error while compiling typescript.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose if you have a variable called "a" having value "apple" and variable called "b" to which you want to assign a value of "a" and you don't want any future change of "b" affects "a" then simply use the code below

var b=Object.assign(a);
//This will stop two-way binding which means any change in b doesn't impact a